# About jmeter scripts failing in production environment

Tags: jmeter, scripting, environment, production

Hi my scripts are working fine in sit environment but same scripts are failing in production environment it's was showing 500 internal server error and also pages are not redirecting to next page

Please give the solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. First run your test with 1-2 virtual users/iterations and inspect requests and responses details via [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. You can also add [Debug Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)/[Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) to see associated [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values. Maybe your correlation fails somewhere somehow

   If you will be able to reproduce your issue you will need to fix your test script accordingly.
2. If the issue occurs only under the load - [HTTP 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) is an **internal server error** so you should inspect your server logs to identify the root cause. It also worth checking resources consumption on the server side using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) to ensure that the server has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc.